# Component throwing errors in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-forms-designer

I've got a small form aplication, that uses a component made by myself.The only problem is, after every run of the program the form throws some error becouse in the Designer of the form for some reasons where the component object is called the IDE adds an **formProduse.** before. Like this

```
private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            System.Windows.Forms.Label iDProdusLabel;
            System.Windows.Forms.Label tipologieLabel;
            System.Windows.Forms.Label descriereLabel;
            System.Windows.Forms.Label uMLabel;
            System.Windows.Forms.Label denumireLabel;
            System.Windows.Forms.Label denumireALabel;
            System.Windows.Forms.Label tVALabel;
            System.Windows.Forms.Label greutateLabel;
            System.Windows.Forms.Label codFurnizorLabel;
            System.Windows.Forms.Label codOpAdaugLabel;
            System.Windows.Forms.Label dataAdaugLabel;
            System.Windows.Forms.Label codOpModificLabel;
            System.Windows.Forms.Label dataModificLabel;
            this.dmProduse = new formProduse.dmProduse(this.components);
            this.tabControl1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();
            this.tabPageInspectare = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
            this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            this.spProduseInspectareBindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
            this.spProduse_Inspectare = new formProduse.spProduse_Inspectare();
            this.tabPage2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.iDProdusTextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.spProduse_InspBindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
            this.tipologieTextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.descriereTextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.uMTextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.denumireTextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.denumireATextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.tVATextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.greutateTextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.codFurnizorTextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.codOpAdaugTextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.dataAdaugDateTimePicker = new System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker();
            this.codOpModificTextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.dataModificDateTimePicker = new System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker();
            this.menuStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip();
            this.aToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.sToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.mToolStripMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
            this.spProduse_InspTableAdapter = new formProduse.spProduse_InspectareTableAdapters.spProduse_InspTableAdapter();
            this.tableAdapterManager = new formProduse.spProduse_InspectareTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager();
            iDProdusLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            tipologieLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            descriereLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            uMLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            denumireLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            denumireALabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            tVALabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            greutateLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            codFurnizorLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            codOpAdaugLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            dataAdaugLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            codOpModificLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            dataModificLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.tabControl1.SuspendLayout();
            this.tabPageInspectare.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.spProduseInspectareBindingSource)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.spProduse_Inspectare)).BeginInit();
            this.tabPage2.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.spProduse_InspBindingSource)).BeginInit();
            this.menuStrip1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
```

If I remove all the 5 appearance of the **formProduse.** the program runs ok.

My errors are

```
Error   1   'formProduse.formProduse.dmProduse' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'  D:\C# Projects\Restaurant2\formProduse\formProduse\formProduse.Designer.cs  45  46  formProduse
Error   2   'formProduse.formProduse.spProduse_Inspectare' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'   D:\C# Projects\Restaurant2\formProduse\formProduse\formProduse.Designer.cs  50  57  formProduse
Error   3   The type name 'spProduse_InspectareTableAdapters' does not exist in the type 'formProduse.formProduse'  D:\C# Projects\Restaurant2\formProduse\formProduse\formProduse.Designer.cs  71  63  formProduse
Error   4   The type name 'spProduse_InspectareTableAdapters' does not exist in the type 'formProduse.formProduse'  D:\C# Projects\Restaurant2\formProduse\formProduse\formProduse.Designer.cs  72  56  formProduse
Error   5   'formProduse.formProduse' does not contain a definition for 'spProduse_InspectareTableAdapters' D:\C# Projects\Restaurant2\formProduse\formProduse\formProduse.Designer.cs  468 64  formProduse



 public partial class dmProduse : Component


    public dmProduse(IContainer container)


   {
        container.Add(this);
        InitializeComponent();
        restaurantConnString = "Data Source=SEBIPC;Initial Catalog=Restaurant;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=*";
        conn = new SqlConnection(restaurantConnString);
        conn.Open();
    }
```

and

```
 public partial class spProduse_Inspectare : global::System.Data.DataSet
```

It's a dataset produced by a StoredProcedure

Comment: public partial class formProduse : Form it's the Form class, I know what the error means, I just don't know why I get it!

Comment: Thanks.  Convention is to have class names with Pascal Cased names so that threw me.  In your code what are `dmProduse` and `spProduse_Inspectare`?  Can you add the code that defines these elements to your example.  The compiler is complaining that these are not Types so you can't call `new` on them.  I missed that on my first comment.

Comment: It looks like your field name and inner class name are the same which seems to be confusing the compiler.  It's hard to say.  Try renaming the fields in the designer to be something different than the class name like `dmProduse1` and `spProduse_Inspectare1`

Comment: Yeah, that seems to do the trick! Still it's very confusing, it should throw an error for wrong object name or something.  THnak you, post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is confusing the field names with the declared names for the inner classes created by the designer.  To remove the conflict you need to make sure that the field names do not match the class names, in your case, for example, using `dmProduse1` instead of `dmProduse`.